# Generic downcast of enum variant

Tags: rust

Suppose the following trait and enum

```
#[enum_dispatch(Components)]
trait Component {}
struct A;
struct B;
impl Component for A {}
impl Component for B {}

#[enum_dispatch]
enum Components {
    A,
    B,
}
```

Now I want to be able to "downcast" an instance of my enum in a generic way, i.e. I want to write

```
let foo = Components::A(A);
dbg!(foo.downcast::<A>()); // Some(&A) : Option<&A>
dbg!(foo.downcast::<B>()); // None : Option<&A>
```

Is this possible at all?

Background: I am trying something akin to but not quite like an ECS and trait objects are a bad fit for various reasons, thus I ended up with `enum_dispatch`. I still need my components in a `HashMap` though but need to access the inner values with a known type. I also really wish for the type to be a parameter and not part of a function name (i.e. something like `foo.downcast_A()`) because I'd like to have higher order functions on top of that:

```
fn apply<C, F>(target: &Components, f: F) 
    where C: Components, F: FnOnce(C)
{
    if let Some(x) = target.downcast::<C>() {
        f(x);
    }
}
```

I was able to achieve something similar with `macro_rules!` but carrying an identifier instead of a typename through a callchain is not very ergonomic.

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering I came up with this:

```
use std::any::TypeId;
use enum_dispatch::enum_dispatch;

#[enum_dispatch(Components)]
trait Component: 'static {
    fn downcast<T: 'static>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        if TypeId::of::<T>() == TypeId::of::<Self>() {
            Some(unsafe { std::mem::transmute(self as *const Self as *const u8) })
        }  else {
            None
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A;
impl Component for A {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B;
impl Component for B {}

#[enum_dispatch]
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Components {
    A,
    B,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Components::A(A);
    dbg!(foo.downcast::<A>()); // Some(A)
    dbg!(foo.downcast::<B>()); // None
}
```

This works but is arguably ugly. Also I don't know if the `'static` requirement on the trait will come back to be a problem. Better solutions are very welcome!

Comment: Did you ever have problems with the `'static` lifetime requirement?

Comment: I honestly gave up on the project after a while. I had other less fun problems as well, like having to come up with an HTML form engine.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work in safe rust. I use a more traitful version of this in my open-source project for a type-safe graph store. I've made a custom derive similar to the enum_dispatch to wash away boilerplates.

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2b0cca6e27b6172aa4118d31b0897b2b

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Apple;
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Person { name: String }

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Component {
    A(Apple),
    P(Person),
}

impl Component {
    fn downcast<T: EnumDowncast<Self>>(self) -> Option<T> {
        T::enum_downcast(self)
    }
    fn downcast_ref<T: EnumDowncast<Self>>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        T::enum_downcast_ref(self)
    }
    fn downcast_mut<T: EnumDowncast<Self>>(&mut self) -> Option<&mut T> {
        T::enum_downcast_mut(self)
    }
}

pub trait EnumDowncast<Enum>: Sized {
    fn enum_downcast(from: Enum) -> Option<Self>;
    fn enum_downcast_ref(from: &Enum) -> Option<&Self>;
    fn enum_downcast_mut(from: &mut Enum) -> Option<&mut Self>;
}

macro_rules! downcast {
    ($component:ident, $variant:ident, $ty: ident) => {
        impl EnumDowncast<$component> for $ty {
            fn enum_downcast(from: $component) -> Option<Self> {
                match from {
                    $component::$variant(item) => Some(item),
                    _ => None,
                }
            }
            fn enum_downcast_ref(from: &$component) -> Option<&Self> {
                match from {
                    $component::$variant(item) => Some(item),
                    _ => None,
                }
            }
            fn enum_downcast_mut(from: &mut $component) -> Option<&mut Self> {
                match from {
                    $component::$variant(item) => Some(item),
                    _ => None,
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

downcast!(Component, A, Apple);
downcast!(Component, P, Person);

fn main() {
    dbg!(Component::A(Apple).downcast::<Apple>());
    dbg!(Component::A(Apple).downcast::<Person>());
    
    let aaa = Component::P(Person { name: "aaa".to_string() });
    let ref1 = aaa.downcast_ref::<Person>();
    let ref2 = aaa.downcast_ref::<Person>();
    let ref3 = aaa.downcast_ref::<Apple>();
    dbg!(ref1, ref2, ref3);
    
    let mut bbb = Component::P(Person { name: "bbb".to_string() });
    if let Some(person) = bbb.downcast_mut::<Person>() {
        person.name = "changed".to_string();
    }
    dbg!(bbb);
}
```